# Fail after resolving Gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Good to all, in advance I would like you to have the best understanding for me since I am new to using android stuido download, version 2.3.3 since version 3.0.1 gave me a lot of problems and someone told me to download the 2.3.3, when I create a new project these errors appear to me, they have apologized my English since I do not know English and I am using a translator hehe

> Error:(37, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12 Show in File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.2.1 Open File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1 Open File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2 Open File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1 Open File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3 Open File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1 Open File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog

And here is the configuration of my gradle I do not know how much you could help me

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
     }

     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
         // in the individual module build.gradle files
         }
     }

     allprojects {
         repositories {
             maven {
                 url 'https://maven.google.com'
             }
             jcenter()
             maven { 'url http://central.maven.org/maven2/' }
             // maven { url 
                 "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
             }
         }
     }
```

And here the other configuration

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cdk.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner  
        android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
                'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
     /* compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'com.squareup', name: 'javawriter', version: '2.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version: '1.3'
    compile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-integration', version: '1.3'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '2.0.1'
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
    compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12' */

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' 
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Keep in mind that the first dependencies are discussed I put them because I thought it was that I was missing those files but even so I fixed that problem so I commented to not delete them not if it is the download server I still have to try one. Many out there say it's the connection but my download speed is 1200 kbts / sec. in the gradle configuration, the offline work mode is unchecked and the recommended option is checked. I had previously tried the local mode and downloaded the latest version, but rather I generated more errors. Please help me I am trying to be as explicit as possible so that they take into account everything I have done please help me thank you in advance

In the stackoverflow forum in Spanish someone told me to update to version 3.0.1 so update and now I get this series of errors, I do not know what you recommend if you stay in version 2.3.3 or version 3.0. 1 really ask them for help because I really like this world and I've even been able to start creating my own app

errors that AS 3.0.1 shows me

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
>   Open File
> Show Details

And here the gradle configuration of AS 3.0.1

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cdk.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
                'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
        core:2.2.2'
     }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

I think I was the most explicit and explanatory that I could there is everything, for help me or get me out of this loop or just tell me you're not done for this haha ​​xD

Comment: This question is too long...

Comment: I consider that the question is detailed, so the comments in other questions always ask for everything I provide, no matter what the recommendation is, since I have done many things like clearing the cache, uninstalling and reinstalling, returning to an older version or update, if they tell me to go back to an older one I will do it if they tell me to stay in this same one, keep in mind that I have really done everything and the mistakes continue and are the same as always.